# How many decimal points for `float` type data can be stored in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: floating-point, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now writing data into Apache IoTDB, and I want to know how many decimal places does the `float` type of Apache IoTDB can retain? This determines whether I can store the data to the precision I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many decimal points for \`float\` type data can be stored in Apache IoTDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749435/how-many-decimal-points-for-float-type-data-can-be-stored-in-apache-iotdb)

Comment: Please don’t post duplicates

Comment: "how many decimal places does the float type" --> certainly `float` uses base 2 and not base 10, so "how many decimal places" is at best: imprecise.  Consider asking how many binary places?

Comment: *One* decimal point. Do yo mean decimal *places?*

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity in my description. What I actually want to know is whether there will be any loss of precision in the data I'm writing. Thanks for your help.it appears that there won't be any loss

Answer (score 2):

The `float` type in Apache IoTDB is an IEEE single-precision (32-bit) float. The `double` type is an IEEE double-precision (64-bit) float.

The correct answer to the question "What is the precision of an IEEE single-precision float?" is "***It depends***".

Also note that *precision*, the number of digits to the right of the decimal (errr...***binary***) point is **not** the same as *accuracy*: floating point number representation trades accuracy for range.

See David Goldberg's 1991 Paper, "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)" from *ACM Computing Surveys*, Vol 23, No 1, March 1991

Answer (score -1):

The precision of the `float` in Apache IoTDB should be the same as the precision in `Java` language.

Comment: True but doesn't answer the question.